# How Universal Turing Machines can do something if a machine doesn't accept?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

In our Computability & Complexity course, we wanted to show that $ALL_{TM}\notin RE$. To do that, we have seen the following claim (I'm summarizing it):

Denote the languages:
$ALL_{TM}=\{(M)|L(M)=\Sigma^*\}$ and $A_{TM}=\{(M,\,w)|w\in L(M)\}$.

> The problem is that we want to simulate $M$ on $w$, but we can actually want to do something if $M$ does not accept $w$. Now, if $M$ rejects $w$ that's fine. We'll wait until it rejects, and go about our business. However, what happens if $M$ does not halt on $w$? Well, then we need some tricks.

> **Claim:** $\overline{A_{TM}} \le_M ALL_{TM}$ (and thus $ALL_{TM} \notin RE$). **Construction:** On input $(M,\,w)$, the reduction constructs the machine $K$ that on input $x$, simulates $M$ on $w$ for $|x|$ steps. If, during this, $M$ accepts, then $K$ rejects. otherwise, $K$ accepts.

Then, when proving the correctness, they claimed the following:

> If $(M,\,w)\in \overline{A_{TM}}$ then $M$ does not accept $w$ and in particular $M$ does not accept it within $|x|$ steps, for all $x$. Thus, $K$ accepts every input so $L(K)=\Sigma^*$ and $(K)\in ALL_{TM}$.

Now, I understand that, take some input, $(M,\,w)$ from $\overline{A_{TM}}$, then if $M$ rejects/not halt on $w$ it means that $(M,\,w)\in \overline{A_{TM}}$ and otherwise it's not.
My problem is with the justification "[...] in particular $M$ does not accept it within $|x|$ steps, for all $x$. Thus, $K$ accepts every input [...]": Lets say that $M$ won't halt on $w$. In this case, when $K$ simulate $M$ - $M$ will not halt - and as a result, $K$ won't halt either, so how come we can say that it'll accept? I understand that in the construction we said that if during the simulation $M$ accepts, then $K$ rejects - but what if in the simulation $M$ doesn't stop at all, how will $K$ have the opportunity to accept? How will it know when to say "enough is enough, I'm going to accept this?"? I can't see what the "trick" is that they applied here.

Comment: Please briefly define $ALL_{TM}$ and $A_{TM}$ and $K$. Not all sources use the same names.

Comment: @plshelp Updated it accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of $K$ is $x$, and $K$ will only simulate $M$ during at most $|x|$ steps. Therefore, there is no situation where the simulation of $K$ does not stop.

If $M$ does not accept $w$, then for any word $x$ of length $n$, executing $M$ during $n$ steps will never reach an accepting state. And so, after $n$ steps of simulation, the TM $K$ will accept the word $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Does it means that we can assume that $|x|$ is arbitrarily big, so no matter in which step $M$ will accept $w$, we will able to reach it as we can choose the length of $x$?

Comment: Note that in the case of your question (and of my answer), $M$ will never accept $w$. But yes, no matter what $x$ we choose, its length will be finite, hence so will be the simulation.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!! :)